# Confusion regarding Tarski's circle-squaring problem

Tags: general-topology, geometry, set-theory, dissection

Wikipedia describes Tarski's circle-squaring problem like this:

> **Tarski's circle-squaring problem** is the challenge, posed by Alfred Tarski in 1925, to take a disc in the plane, cut it into finitely many pieces, and reassemble the pieces so as to get a square of equal area.

To get to my question, I need to discuss a little bit about two very different types of dissection problem. (Note: The notation $\cong$ means congruence.)

Now, from my understanding, most dissection puzzles can be formalized as in the following way: *Let $A$ and $B$ be regular open subsets of the plane. Can you write $\overline A=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n\overline{A_i}$ and $\overline B=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n\overline{B_i}$ such that the $A_i$ (resp. $B_i$) are disjoint regular open sets, and such that for each $i$, $A_i\cong B_i$?* (Regular open sets are those which are the interiors of their closures.)

The benefit of such a formalization is that we do not have to worry about individual points. For example, Dudeney famously provided a dissection of a triangle into a square. (In fact, it's a *hinged* dissection, as you can see demonstrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfHaSK1_J8c).) Dudeney's dissection easily fits within this paradigm.

[image: Dudeney's dissection of a triangle into a square]

However, we can also ask the following sort of dissection puzzle: *Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of the plane. Can you write $A=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nA_i$ and $B=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nB_i$ such that the $A_i$ (resp. $B_i$) are disjoint sets, and such that for each $i$, $A_i\cong B_i$?*

This is a *much* stricter thing to ask; we now have to care about individual points! Dudeney's dissection does not satisfy this version of dissection at all. (On the other hand, this *does* describe the dissection in the Banach–Tarski paradox, for example.)

For the sake of giving names to things, let's call the former the *classical* dissection problem, and the latter the *shapes-as-sets* dissection problem. (I choose this name for it because believe it was only made possible by the modern *shapes-as-sets paradigm*, so useful in topology and related fields, in which shapes are modeled as the set of points lying on them, and in which (conversely) there are no restrictions on which sets of points can be considered shapes.)

Now, to get back to Tarski. I see on Wikipedia that Tarski's circle-squaring problem has been solved in the affirmative: it *is* possible to decompose a disc into finitely many pieces and rearrange them into a square. I would like to ask for clarification: **is it the *classical* circle-squaring problem or the *shapes-as-sets* circle-squaring problem that has been solved** (in the senses described above?

Furthermore, on the assumption that it is the latter: **is the *classical* circle-squaring problem (as formalized above in terms of regular open sets and their closures) possible**? My instinct is no, but I'm not sure how to prove it. I see Wikipedia has a reference to an impossibility result when the pieces are cut by Jordan curves, but it's not immediately obvious to me that this is equivalent.

EDIT: I'm realizing belatedly that the classical problem could be formalized equivalently and more simply in terms of regular closed sets (that is, closed sets which are the closures of their interiors) whose interiors are disjoint.

EDIT2: I just realized, these two are the *same definition* relativized to different Boolean algebras. The former is the [Boolean algebra of regular open sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_open_set#Properties) and the latter is the power set Boolean algebra; these are both complete Boolean algebras.

Comment: Perhaps a better name would be "the _shapes-as-pointsets paradigm_", but the name was long enough already. (I would also like to point out that topologists don't actually use the word "shape" to refer to pointsets, quite sensibly so because pointsets can be quite wild. But when you talk about "pieces", suddenly it gets a little ambiguous.)

Comment: I'm also slightly worried that my formalization of the classical case might not capture exactly what I want. For example: it does not actually guarantee that area is preserved, since open sets do not necessarily have the same areas as their closures.

Comment: @EricWofsey Surely we would need the sum total of all the edgelengths to be the same, which would happen iff the square and triangle have the same perimeter, and they don't

Comment: (As for why the regularity condition is important: it isn't, really, when it comes to whether a dissection is _possible_, I think; but if we don't include regularity we have the unfortunate side effect that we can subtract arbitrary closed nowhere dense sets from the pieces without affecting anything. If we phrased it in terms of open sets, without regularity we could _add_ arbitrary closed nowhere dense sets.)